# How can I compile two files in java on Command prompt

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a program which has two files DrumKit.java and DrumKitTestDrive.java. I am successfully able to compile DrumKit.java but get an error msg when I try to compile the DrumKitTestDrive.java file.

Below is the error message:

```
DrumKit.java:1: error: duplicate class: Drumkit
class Drumkit{
^
DrumKitTestDrive.java:4: error: cannot access DrumKit
DrumKit d = new DrumKit();
^
  bad source file: .\DrumKit.java
    file does not contain class DrumKit
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

Both files are in the same folder.
May someone help me that how can I compile. Any response would be helpful. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Also make sure you're not defining class DrumKit in both files.

Comment: You were not able to compile DrumKit,java. The first error message says so.

Comment: appreciate the help and was successfully able to run the program

Answer (score 0):

You can compile multiple files as,

```
javac DrumKitTestDrive.java DrumKit.java
```

Alternatively you can also compile all Java files in current directory as,

```
javac *.java
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help and it worked.

Comment: No. You should move to the directory containing the top of the package structure.

Answer (score -1):

You can compile both classes and have to use javac command for compilation for source code

```
javac DrumKit.java DrumKitTestDrive.java
```

if you have multiple java files present at a specific directory then you can directly compile from there itself by going to that specific location.

Let say your java files are in the directory

```
D:\javaProgram
```

you have to move to this specific location and use below command compile all java files

```
javac *.java
```

Comment: No. You should move to the directory containing the top of the package structure.